# Does Active Directory alone is not enough to secure hadoop?

Tags: active-directory, security, ldap, kerberos, hadoop

I am trying to **secure Hadoop environment installed in windows**. So basically I started to analyse how to secure a Unix-based hadoop cluster. Have gone through various links related to Kerberos and other Apache Add-ons(**Knox/ Rhino/ Sentry**).. Yet to check each one of them,

In the mean time, found Active Directory which is about User Management(LDAP). Also it seems AD has Kerberos installed in it by default. So **if AD contains LDAP and Kerberos with itself, cant we use Active Directory alone to secure hadoop cluster?**

All these Google suggestions [Links](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=active%20directory%20hadoop), suggests a framework to secure any one of the company's pre formed Unix-based hadoop cluster as,

1. Authorization  - Active Directory(LDAP),
2. Authentication - Kerberos

To come again, My question is cant we use Active Directory alone to secure a hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, in the [manual](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html), Kerberos with SPNEGO is supported out of the box:

> Similarly to Hadoop RPC, Hadoop HTTP web-consoles can be configured to require Kerberos authentication using HTTP SPNEGO protocol (supported by browsers like Firefox and Internet Explorer).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Let me check about 'Hadoop HTTP web-consoles'. But, it would be pleasing if you answer my question too regarding Active Directory.